# Sending an ethereum transaction with ethers.js and metamask

Tags: metamask, ethers.js

I've tried two different ways, and have looked through ethers.js documentation, and I just haven't been able to figure it out.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  This is in a browser.

```js
trans(web3,ethers);

async function trans(web3,ethers,provider){
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        var web3Provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3.currentProvider);
        var signer = web3Provider.getSigner();

        const parameters = [
            {
              gasLimit: "0x2710",
              gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("1.0", "gwei").toHexString(),

              from: this.state.provider._web3Provider.selectedAddress,
              to: this.state.provider._web3Provider.selectedAddress,
              value: 0,
              data: "0x1"
            }
          ];

          const payload = {
            method: "eth_sendTransaction",
            params: parameters,
            from: this.state.provider._web3Provider.selectedAddress
          };

          this.state.provider._web3Provider.sendAsync(payload, function(
            err,
            response
          ) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log(response.result);
            }
          });
```

and this way...

```js
trans(web3,ethers);

async function trans(web3,ethers,provider){
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        var web3Provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3.currentProvider);
        var signer = web3Provider.getSigner();
        let tx = await signer.sendTransaction({
                to: 0xC046B25B3B5F960E1D7004499FBd8dc4C1BDe2f4,
                value: 1000,
        });
        let signature = await signer.signMessage("Hello world");
        // web3Provider.getBalance("0x9Ff548c1B3eA3dd123AFE39C759dDA548009B6C8").then(function(balance) {
        //   var etherString = ethers.utils.formatEther(balance);
        //   console.log("Balance: " + etherString);
        // });
      }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error message? It seems you are using it from a react app, can you try it with a simple html?

Comment: you can replace signer by other accounts ... which can be found here: [user1, user2, user3, ...addrs] = await ethers.getSigners();

Answer (score 12):

I was able to do it with this code below:

```js
import { ethers, utils } from 'ethers';


export async function payWithMetamask(sender, receiver, strEther) {
    console.log(`payWithMetamask(receiver=${receiver}, sender=${sender}, strEther=${strEther})`)

    let ethereum = window.ethereum;


    // Request account access if needed
    await ethereum.enable();


    let provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);

    // Acccounts now exposed
    const params = [{
        from: sender,
        to: receiver,
        value: ethers.utils.parseUnits(strEther, 'ether').toHexString()
    }];

    const transactionHash = await provider.send('eth_sendTransaction', params)
    console.log('transactionHash is ' + transactionHash);
}
```

Comment: ncaught (in promise) Error: value must be a string (argument="value", value=10, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=units/5.5.0)

Answer (score 10):

The way I was able to do it as of March 2, 2022 was as follow:

```js
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
// get a signer wallet!
const signer = provider.getSigner();

// Creating a transaction param
const tx = {
    from: DefaultAccount,
    to: "0x611E72c39419168FfF07F068E76a077588225798",
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.05"),
    nonce: await provider.getTransactionCount(DefaultAccount, "latest"),
    gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(10000),
    gasPrice: ethers.utils.hexlify(parseInt(await provider.getGasPrice())),
};

signer.sendTransaction(tx).then((transaction) => {
    console.dir(transaction);
    alert("Send finished!");
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will work but it would be better to follow the new EIP-1559 (on supported networks) instead of providing legacy gasPrice param